# problem with ckeditor in react js in @ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

good time everyone
I have a project in which I used ckeditor. At first, I used the @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic version and my problem was that when I copied a text from office, it only produced the p tag and the text lost all its styles. To add this feature that preserves its style text, I needed to use the @ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic version, but installing and configuring this version was a completely different thing that I couldn't launch from the ckeditor documentation.
I want all the basic functions of the build-classic version, and besides, when the text is pasted, I want no style to change and even the fonts to be read, but reading the fonts is not a priority.
I want to provide the user with fonts that I have in the project and the user can use those fonts.
If someone can send such a thing with all the details, I would be very grateful.
Thanks to all

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGzJi.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share code as text, not as images.